# Constant in probability

Tags: probability

A six face die is so biased that it is twice as likely to show an even number than  an odd number when thrown.

The above statement is a part of a probability problem.

Let the probability be $P(O)= k$
so $P(E) = 2k$

Now we have 3 even numbers and 3 odd numbers so:

$3\times 2k + 3k = 1 $

$\implies k = 1/9$

But author's solution says that $k= 1/3$. I don't understand why my method is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all odd numbers are equally likely, the probability of a *particular* odd number is $\frac19$, but the probability that *any* odd number appears is $\frac13$.

Answer (score 0):

here $O=\{1,3,5\}$ and $E=\{2,4,6\}$.

We have $P(E)+P(O)=1$

hence $k+2k=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(O U E) = P(O) + P(E) $

$P(O U E) = k + 2k$

$P(O U E) = 3k$

but since OUE is all possible outcomes $P( O U E )$ must be $1$ or 100%

therefore $3k = 1 $

$k = \frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

There are two different $k$s in your question: the value $k$ used by the author, and the value $k$ used by you. Let's call them $k_A$ for "author" and $k_R$ for "reader."

For the author, $k_A$ is the probability that the number shown on the die is not even. If the number on the die is $X$, then $P(X\in\{1,3,5\}) = k_A.$

For you, $k_R$ is the probability that the number shown on the die is $1,$
that is, $P(X = 1) = k_R.$
You also say that $P(X = 3) = k_R$ and $P(X = 5) = k_R,$ so for you,
$P(X\in\{1,3,5\}) = 3k_R.$

You have used $3k_R$ to represent the probability of the same event that the author says has probability $k_A.$ So if you are both computing that probability correctly, we should find that $3k_R = k_A.$

And indeed, $3\times \frac19 = \frac13.$

The thing to remember in the context of a variable that can take on the values $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},$ is that $P(\text{Odd}) = p$
means $P(X\in\{1,3,5\}) = p,$
not $P(X=1) = P(X=3) = P(X=5) = p.$